# C - Cut a string after last "/" in string

Tags: c, string, character, cut

Is is somehow possible to cut of a string after the last time the specific character "/" comes up in the string?
For example:
/one/two/three/four would be cut into /one/two/three

I have tried something like this in a loop to chop it into multiple pieces:

```
substr = strstr(line, "/");
nextSubstr= substr+1; 
length = strlen(line) - strlen(substr);
substr = strndup(line, length);
```

but I feel like it should be a more effective way to do this.. Thanks for any help

Comment: yeah I have read that one, but they cut off after a specific character I think and not the last instance of that specific character, corrcet me if im wrong!

Comment: You could, well, just write code for it, iterating the strig backwards until you find the char, (or the start), and insert a NUL terminator after it if found.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the standard function [`strrchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) to find the last occurance:

```
void truncate_at_last(char *s, char t)
{
  char * const last = strrchr(s, t);
  if(last != NULL)
    *last = '\0';
}
```

The above modifies the string in place, by just chopping off the part after the last instance of `t` (and `t` itself). If you want a new string instead, you of course need to allocate and copy:

```
char * get_prefix(const char *s, char t)
{
  const char * last = strrchr(s, t);
  if(last != NULL)
  {
    const size_t len = (size_t) (last - s);
    char * const n = malloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(n, s, len);
    n[len] = '\0';
    return n;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this solved it well!